# Копирование элементов одномерного вектора в двумерный

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую! Мне необходимо составить двумерный вектор(таблицу), строки которого будут заполняться одномерными векторами. Одномерные вектора являются представлением двоичного числа, которое на каждой итерации должно меняться на определенный шаг. Основная проблема заключается в копировании значений одномерного вектора в необходимую строку двумерного вектора. Пробовал следующим образом:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        table[i][j] = to_binary(startvalue)[j];
        cout << table[i][j] << " ";
    }
    startvalue += step;
}
```

где `to_binary(startvalue)`- функция, возвращающая вектор битов переведенного числа. Однако на экран ничего не выводится, и ошибок компилятор не обнаруживает. Используя отладку смог установить, что проблема заключается в строке `table[i][j] = to_binary(startvalue)[j];`, но решить ее не удалось.
Заранее благодарю всех за оказанную помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если я правильно Вас понял...Вы дали слишком мало данных, поэтому, вот код, выдаёт число в двоичном представлении 25 раз, последовательно увеличивая его на заданный *step*.

```
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

using std::vector;
using std::bitset;

vector<int> to_binary(int sv);

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> table(25); 
    int startvalue(5);
    int step(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++)
    {
        auto vect = to_binary(startvalue);
        for(int j = 0;j<vect.size();j++)
        {
            table[i].push_back(vect[j]);
            std::cout << table[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        startvalue += step;
    }
    return 0;
}

vector<int> to_binary(int sv)
{
    bitset<32> num(sv);
    vector<int> res;
    for (int i(0); i < num.size(); i++)
        res.push_back(num[i]);
    return res;
}
```

На консоль выдаётся всё корректно.

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что bitset корректно работает только с целочисленными примитивами, для вещественных нужно использовать что-то другое(можно написать алгоритм вручную, это уже детали).

P.S.:

> bitset<32> num(sv);

32 - потому что размер int в 32 разрядной архитектуре(если мне не изменяет память, и я говорю все верно) равен 4 байтам * 8 бит = 32 бита.